# 'where' and slice at the same time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a list of logicals `test` and a list of indices `i` of the same length. Now I want to select `a[i]` where `test == True`. Naturally I use `np.where`, e.g.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(4)
test = np.array([True, False, False, True])
i = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

b = np.where(test, a[i], -1)
print(b)
```

But now I encounter the case where the indices in `i` are not valid indices of `a` where `test == False`. E.g.

```py
test = np.array([True, False, False, True])
i = np.array([0, 6, 6, 0])
```

the above code of course fails because the slice does not work. But since I was not interested in the slice where `test == False`, how can I avoid its evaluation?

Of course a work-around is

```py
b = np.where(test, a[np.where(test, i, 0)], -1)
```

but this I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification on your solution:

```
b = np.where(test, a[i*test], -1)
```

It works even if `i` is out of bound when `test` is `False`. Trick is multiplying index to `True` will return same index whereas multiplying index to `False` turn it to `0`.

Another easy solution is this:

```
b = -1*np.ones_like(a)
b[test] = a[i[test]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second solution really didn't occur to me.

Comment: @TomdeGeus You are welcome. I am not sure which one is faster. I would suggest to time it if performance matters.